# MPV Playback progress bar display

Tags: video-player, smplayer

How do I access the MPV progress bar displayed in the picture? The only thing I am aware of is Shift+P bringing up that archaic looking progress bar. Is this some kind of frontend similar to SMplayer?

https://mpv.io/images/mpv-screenshot-f4a039a3.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem. Upon a suggestion from someone else who was helping me trouble shoot, I noticed that the version I was using was actually out of date. The mpv website has a 3rd party PPA listed for ubuntu that I neglected to use. I instead had installed using the standard ubuntu repository without adding the 3rd party PPA.

```
ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests
```

Found at: https://mpv.io/installation/

After realizing this is probably causing me to be out of date I added the PPA above, ran `sudo apt-get update` and then reinstalled mpv. At this point I was able to see the on screen controls.